# In firebase, how do you secure a specific key whilst allowing access to others

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Having issues getting my head round firebase security yet again.

Say I have the following json data structure in firebase

```
{
  "users" : {
    "userguid001" : {
    "name" : "Test User 1",
    "email" : "test1@test.com",
    "emailverified" : "true",
    "otherinfo1": "some text",
    "otherinfo2": "some more text",
    "otherinfo3": "and some more text"
  },
  "userguid002" : {
    "name" : "Test User 2",
    "email" : "test2@test.com",
    "emailverified" : "true",
    "otherinfo1": "some text",
    "otherinfo2": "some more text",
    "otherinfo3": "and some more text"
  },
  "userguid003" : {
    "name" : "Test User 3",
    "email" : "test3@test.com",
    "emailverified" : "true",
    "otherinfo1": "some text",
    "otherinfo2": "some more text",
    "otherinfo3": "and some more text"
  }
}
```

}

Is there any way I can allow users (who know a userguid) general read/write access to the specific users branch and at the same time disallow write access to specific keys within that branch - namely "emailverified" and "email"?

I need this as we do some server side processing to validate email addresses and we dont want people to be able to enter verified email addresses without coming via our validation system.

I was thinking security rules something along the lines of the following but this obviously doesnt work with the way read/write logic flows down in firebase:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      "$userid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "true",
        "emailverified" : {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "false"
        },
        "email" : {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only way I can think to do this at this stage is to split it into two root branches (one the users can read/write to and one that they can only read from). I have seen this method mentioned a few times but just wondering if there is anything I can do to keep it all under one branch.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question but I struggle to understand some of the examples being presented in many questions as they dont seem to match my requirements exactly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [security rules cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade) and [cannot be used as filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter) the answer would have to be no. Please check out [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/) and save yourself some thrashing here.

The solution is to split private and public data to their own paths.

```
/user_profiles/$user_id/email_verified
/private_user_data/$user_id/email
```

Comment: Still processing the guide. Is it not possible to do via a validate rule? Like:

`"emailverified": { ".validate": false },
"$other": { ".validate": true }`

Comment: Firstly, .validate rules only apply to writing data, so they won't affect read access. Additionally, if you attempt to read a path and **any** of the data is not accessible, then the **entire** read will fail.