# Firebase - splitting tables between secure and insecure fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

Is there any best practice for structuring Firebase tables/objects between secure data fields (which users are not trusted to update themselves) and insecure data, which they may set themselves?

For example, a user should be free to change their name or preferences inside their own `users` object, but they should not be free to change settings such as if they're a paid user, is their email confirmed, etc. Or to user a specific example, `user.name` should be editable by the user directly, while `user.email` should only be changed via our own API, which would then update Firebase's record.

This seems like it must be a common requirement, because I see it in basically every table we need. e.g. we have `users`, we have `projects`, we have `tasks` within a project, etc. And for each of those data types, there are always fields which are user-editable and ones that are not.

So which type of approach is best practice? Here are two possibilities:

```
secure_data:
  users:
    user1:
      email:
    user2:
  projects:
  tasks:
insecure_data:
  users:
    user1:
      name:
    user2:
  projects:
  tasks:
```

Or:

```
users:
  user1:
    secure:
      email:
    insecure:
      name:
projects:
   project1:
     secure:
     insecure:
tasks:
```

By the way, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084231/3005034) implies that my first option above should be used, but I wanted to structure this question more generally to see if there's indeed any best practice for this.

Comment: When you are speaking of letting the user change their name but not their email. Do you have a app or something else that enables the user to make those kinds of changes? i.e. how are you currently allowing a user to change their name?

Comment: "Is there a best practice" is extremely broad. It's also frequently a substitute for "Write this code for me." Please attempt to be specific in your questions and to provide a detailed use case, including all constraints, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Jay there will be a webapp initially, and later an iPhone app. But the point was more about access control and the "worst case" that someone is attempting to use expert knowledge of Firebase libraries and data structure to exploit my service.

Comment: @Kato my intuition was the opposite! i.e. if I were to give a very specific use case (my own), then in *that* case I'm basically asking for "write it for me". Whereas by attempting to make the question generic, it's more useful to a wider audience. At risk of being too broad of course. But anyway, you answered it regardless, thanks :)

Comment: Cheers, @rgareth; glad to help. Stack Overflow's philosophy is to be specific and provide as much detail as possible upfront. That avoids [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and helps you get better answers. You'd be surprised how many people will have a similar use case. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more on the Stack Overflow philosophy.

Comment: I was asking about the current app because you can implement security features in your app that can add control as to what a user can or can not do. Couple that with Firebase Rules and it's a very powerful, flexible and expandable way to control app data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an entire guide covering best practices, including topics on [data structures](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) and [security related to auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html), which includes a live demo.

As the [previously linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084231/3005034) question already covers the use cases for reading secured data, I'll also assume that you're not asking the same question, and that you're only interested in write restrictions. If you want read restrictions, then this question is a duplicate; you won't be able to iterate or query on a path unless all data in that path is readable.

Write restrictions are very straightforward; only grant write access to the relevant fields.

For example, if a user should be able to write to email but not paid status:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "users": {
        "$uid": {
           // allow write access to email but not paid status
           "email": ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I would add my own clarification then, as now I see there are really three types of user data: public/editable (user has read/write), public/protected (user can read but not write), and private (keep a separate table of user data that they cannot not even read). The two public types of data can be included in a "typical" users table that the user has direct access to, whereas the private table needs to maintained by some other process (e.g. server-side API)

Comment: You may be overthinking this a bit, as I did initially, and forgive me if you already have your brain wrapped around it. In FB there is only one 'kind' of data. There's no concept of user, app or public data*, it's just data. Any user can read/write to any node. That being said, Rules add structure to who/how the data is read/written. Rules don't filter the data - it's just a rule as to who and what data can be read or written. Also, there is no real server-side API, other than the Rules and Firebase doesn't have tables although it seems that way. 'There is no spoon'